# Stop SSRS from Rounding UP

Tags: reporting-services

I need for my raw data to display with one in SSRS.

Example: From my data from SQL database the data returns 0.228070 however in SSRS its displays 23%, but I need 22.8%

I tried using 'F2' and 'N2'

Comment: I had to write this is an expressionn...there are some other columns doing some calculations

Answer (score 3):

Try use the text box properties

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use an expression e.g.:

=FormatPercent(Fields!Fieldname.Value,1)

This will override the text box properties.